Intersection Numbers in Fulton's algebraic curves
I am reading the section on intersection numbers of algebraic curves written by Fulton https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf , and I have a question about Theorem 3 at page 37. In the sentence "If $F$ and $G$ have no common components, $I(P,F\cap G)$ is finite.", why is $I(P,F\cap G)$ is finite?
Here is my thought process:
Assume that $P=(0,0)$, and that all the components of $F$ and $G$ pass through $P$
$I(P,F\cap G)=\dim_k(\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)/(F,G))$, since $\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)/(F,G)=k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(F,G)\cong k[X,Y]/(F,G)$, $I(P,F\cap G)=\dim_k(k[X,Y]/(F,G))$.
Is the process above correct? How to calculate $\dim_k(k[X,Y]/(F,G))$, when $F$ and $G$ have no common components?
Here is theorem 3:
There is a unique intersection number $I(P,F\cap G)$ defined for all plane curves $F$, $G$, and all points $P\in\mathbb{A}^2$, satisfying properties (1)-(7). It is given by the formula $$I(P,F\cap G)=\dim_k(\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)/(F,G)).$$
And (1)-(7) are:
(1) $I(P,F\cap G)$ is a nonnegative integer for any $F$, $G$ and $P$ such that $F$ and $G$ intersct properly at $P$. $I(P,F\cap G)=\infty$ if $F$ and $G$ do not intersect properly at $P$.
(2) $I(P,F\cap G)=0$ if and only if $P\notin P\cap Q$. $I(P,F\cap G)$ depends only on the components of $F$ and $G$ that pass through $P$. And $I(P,F\cap G)=0$ if $F$ or $G$ is a nonzero constant.
(3) If $T$ is an affine change of coordinates on $\mathbb{A}^2$, and $T(Q)=P$, then $I(P,F\cap G)=I(Q,F^T\cap G^T)$.
(4) $I(P,F\cap G)=I(P,G\cap F).$
(5) $I(P,F\cap G)\geq m_P(F)m_P(G)$, with equality occuring if and only if $F$ and $G$ have not tangent lines in common at $P$.
(6) The intersection numbers should add when we take unions of curves: If $F=\prod F_i^{r_i}$ and $G=\prod G_j^{s_j}$, then $I(P,F\cap G)=\sum_{i,j}r_is_jI(P,F_i\cap G_j).$
(7) The last requirement is probably the least intuitive. If $F$ is irreducible, it says that $I(P,F\cap G)$ should depend only on the image of $G$ in $\Gamma(F)$. Or, for arbitrary, $$I(P,F\cap G)=I(P,F\cap(G+AF))$$ for any $A\in k[X,Y]$.

If $F$ and $G$ have no common components, note that $\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)/(F,G)\cong k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(F,G)$, hence $$\dim_k(\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)/(F,G))=\dim_k(k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(F,G)).$$
First, we shall to show that $Z(F,G)$ is finite. Write $k[X,Y]$ as $k[X][Y]$ and $k[Y][X]$, since $\gcd(F,G)=1$, there exist $h(X)\in k[X],l(Y)\in k[Y]$ and $u(X,Y),v(X,Y),u'(X,Y),v'(X,Y)\in k[X,Y]$ such that $$u(X,Y)F(X,Y)+v(X,Y)G(X,Y)=h(X)$$ and $$u'(X,Y)F(X,Y)+v'(X,Y)G(X,Y)=l(Y).$$
Say $\overline{X},\overline{Y}$ are the image of $X,Y$ in $\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)/(F,G)$ respectively. We may thus assume that $h(X)=X^sh_0(X),s\geq 1$ and $h_0(0)\neq 0$, then $h_0(X)$ is a unit in $\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)$. Since $h(X)=X^sh_0(X)\in (F,G)$, $X^s\in (F,G)$. Similarly, $l(Y)=Y^tl_0(Y)$ where $l_0(Y)$ is a unit in $\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)$, and therefore $Y^t\in(F,G)$.
Now, we shall to show that $\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)/(F,G)$ is generated by $1,\overline{X},\overline{Y},\cdots,\overline{X}^{s-1}\overline{Y}^{t-1}$ as $k$-vector space, by note that $\overline{X}^s=\overline{0}$ and $\overline{Y}^t=\overline{0}$.
Let $W=span_k\{1,\overline{X},\overline{Y},\cdots,\overline{X}^{s-1}\overline{Y}^{t-1}\}$, we claim that $W=\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)/(F,G)$. Let $\varphi=\sum\limits_{i+j\leq N}a_{ij}X^iY^j\in\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)$, then $\overline{\varphi}=\sum\limits_{i<s,j<t}a_{ij}\overline{X}^i\overline{Y}^j\in W$. Let $\psi=\frac{a(X,Y)}{b(X,Y)}\in\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)$ where $b(0,0)\neq 0$. Without loss of general, assume that $b(X,Y)=1-u_0X-v_0Y$ where $u_0,v_0\in k[X,Y]$. Let $\psi_1=a(X,Y)[1+(u_0X+v_0Y)+\cdots+(u_0X+v_0Y)^{s+t-1}]$, then $\psi_1b(X,Y)=a(X,Y)[1-(u_0X+v_0Y)^{s+t}]$, where $a(X,Y)\in\Gamma(\mathbb{A}^2)=k[X,Y]$ and $\overline{(u_0X+v_0Y)^{s+t}}=\overline{0}$. Hence, in $\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)/(F,G)$, we have $$\overline{\psi_1\cdot b(X,Y)}=\overline{a(X,Y)}.$$ On the other hand, $\psi b=a$, and therefore $\overline{\psi\cdot b}=\overline{a}$, hence $\overline{\psi_1\cdot b}=\overline{\psi\cdot b}$. Note that $b$ is a unit in $\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)$, hence $\overline{\psi}=\overline{\psi_1}\in W$. That is, $$\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)/(F,G)=span_k\{1,\overline{X},\overline{Y},\cdots,\overline{X}^{s-1}\overline{Y}^{t-1}\},$$ and thus $\dim_k(\mathscr{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)/(F,G))\leq st$, i.e., $I(P,F\cap G)$ is finite.
